# Is there a shared single-screen option for Terraria co-op on PS4?

Tags: ps4, terraria-console

I'm playing *Terraria* co-op on my PS4 with other players, locally. When they connect, the game goes into split-screen, and each player has their own quarter of the screen.

Is there a way to have all four players share the same screen? So we can play together on the same single screen?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, Terraria has no option for an un-split split screen experience.